# If a point in lng and lat is on line Segment or it only 2 meters away

Tags: javascript, python, c#, geometry

Here is what I am trying to achieve,( please do not put duplicate has I cannot ask questions),I want to find if the  point cLng, cLat is on the Segment line aLng,alat to bLng,bLng. My problem is that my distance check is not working at 2.00 meters which is EPSILON.
Any help in improving this code would be much appreciated.

```
        var crossProduct = (cLat - aLat) * (bLng - aLng) - (cLng - aLng) * (bLat - aLat);
        if (Math.Abs(crossProduct) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        
        var dotProduct = (cLng - aLng) * (bLng - aLng) + (cLat - aLat) * (bLat - aLat);

        var squaredLength = (bLng - aLng) * (bLng - aLng) + (bLat - aLat) * (bLat - aLat);
        

        var param = -1d;
        if (squaredLength != 0) //in case of 0 length line
        {
            param = dotProduct / squaredLength;
        }

        double xx = param < 0 ? aLng : param >  1 ? bLng: aLng + param * bLng - aLng;
        double yy = param < 0 ? aLat : param >  1 ? bLat: aLat + param * bLat - aLat; 
        var dx = cLng - xx;
        var dy = cLat - yy;
        var sqrt = Math.Sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        return sqrt < EPSILON;
```

Comment: What is the reason for tagging multiple languages?

Comment: I  can convert into any language that was the reason why

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but shouldn't you just test if the coordinates of C satisfy the equation that represents the line that goes through A and B?

Comment: @MarcG I just want to know if the point is on the line or close to the line nothing else so if its online fine if its 2 meters away fine.  Cross Product tells you its on the line segment.